# Call Alpine js from javascript

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I have Alpinajs and Splidejs on page. I want to change aplinajs variable from splide event

```js
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.data('titles', () => ({
    slidetitle_1: true,
    toggle(n) {
      this["slidetitle_" + n] = true
    }
  }))
})
```

then when in slider event

```
var splide = new Splide('.splide').mount();
splide.on( 'active', function (t) {
  // not working
  Alpine.data('titles', () => {
    this["slidetitle_" + 1] = true;
  });
  // not working
  Alpine.$data.titles.toggle(1);
});
```

but none of this working

Comment: `but none of this working` - OK, how is it not working? Please show us any relevant errors / messages

Comment: no errors to. but noting happens

Comment: I see the comments you have indicating which lines of code are failing. Am I correct in assuming that the fallback you provide to `splide.on` is never being called? It would be way easier to help with a full, working code sample, either on CodeSandbox or CodePen or JSFiddle…